# Different sections in a table (multiple empty rows). Create a conditional loop that inputs an empty row to the correct section - VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I have an issue I'm unable to resolve myself and was wondering if anyone here could help me. I have table with a lot of values which are broken down into different sections (separated by an empty row). I need to be able to control where a new row is inserted with the use of a macro.

What I would like to do is to create a macro with conditions so that I can control where an empty row are to be inserted. My take is to create separate buttons next to each sections (before an empty row) that assigns a value so that loop may skip through x number of empty rows before inserting a new row. My first take is like this:

Sub InsertNewRow()

```
Dim erow As Integer
Dim number As Integer 'number of empty rows to skip
Dim count As Integer 'to keep track on number of empty rows to skip
Dim LastRow As Long

erow = ActivityInput.UsedRange.Rows.count
count = 0


For Each l In erow

    Do While i <> ""
    Next erow

count = count + 1

If element = count Then

     'Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

'This is as far as I got. I don't know how to make the macro go to the last row of the current section... any suggestions?

..

To clarify, I would like to add macro(s) (bottons) that helps the user to insert new rows. If the user is at section 3 (2 empty rows have been passed which separates the different sections), I would like the user to be able to click on the macro (button) which then subsequently adds a new row to the current section.

Any ideas?:/

Regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub InsertNewRow(X As Integer)

```
Dim count As Integer
count = 0

For i = 1 To ActivityInput.Range("X[ABC]")(i)

    If i <> "" Then Next i


    ElseIf X = count Then

        Cells(l, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert

    Else

    count = count + 1

Next l
```

End Sub